# Region with Cheapest EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a small server on AWS that the networking and other thing is not that much important. Threfore, hosting an EC2 in any region does not matter to me. I view cost as the biggest factor in choosing the region.\

My server :
t3.small with 2 Gb ram, 2 CPU, 8 Gb storage.

I wonder if anyone has this kind of experience and which region is the cheapest one?

Comment: It's as easy as a simple Google search: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/.

Comment: Depending on what your server does, you might find Lambda to be the cheapest option.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that an [Amazon Lightsail package](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/) will be a lower-cost option for you rather than using Amazon EC2.

It offers a fixed-price for compute, storage and data transfer.